# Markov Chain matrix issue

Tags: probability, matrices, markov-chains

I'm doing the following problem that upsets me :
Let's consider an urn with $n+1$ red and white balls ( at least one white ball at the beginning ) in it and repeat the experiment :
- Pick two balls from the urn:

$\bullet$ If they are of the same color we replace them by one red and one white.

$\bullet$ If they are from different color we put them back in the bowl.

Let $X_k$ be the number of white after $k$ manipulations and 
$U_k=P(X_k=i)$ for $i$ between $1$ and $n$

I’m studying the case where $n=4$ and I need to find the matrix $A$ such that
$$U_{k+1}=AU_k.$$

I used that 
$$P(X_{k+1}=p)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(X_k=p | X_k=i) P(X_k=i)$$
Hence I've deduced 
$$A_{ij}=P(X_{k+1}=i+1| X_k=j)$$

Seeing the problem, the non null values of the matrix are when $\left|j-i\right| \leq 1$ which gives by taking each experiment in account :
\begin{align*}
P(X_{k+1}=i | X_k=i)   &= \frac{i\left(n+1-i\right)}{n(n+1)}, \\
P(X_{k+1}=i-1 | X_k=i) &= \frac{i\left(i-1\right)}{n(n+1)}, \\
P(X_{k+1}=i+1| X_k=i)  &= \frac{(n-i)\left(n+1-i\right)}{n(n+1)}.
\end{align*}

The matrix I've found evaluating with $i$ and $j$ is
$$
  \frac{1}{20}
  \begin{pmatrix}
     4 & 2 & 0 &  0 \\
    12 & 6 & 6 &  0 \\
     0 & 6 & 6 & 12 \\
     0 & 0 & 2 &  4
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

which is false and I wonder why and how I could find the matrix $A$. Any help ?

Comment: I is between 1 and n in the exercise is that a mistake ?

Comment: There are $n+1$ balls, i edit

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand how $X_k$ could be null. If there are only one ball white and $n$ red, then it is not possible to pick $2$ white so you can only pick one red one white => changes nothing or you pick $2$ red and then there are one more white at the next step.

Comment: You’re right. I was getting something backwards. That same argument also shows that you can never remove the last red ball, either. Anyway, the columns of your matrix don’t add up to $1$, so you’re clearly either miscalculating the transition probabilities or missing something else.

Comment: That s why i came here aha x)

Comment: The expressions for the three possible nonzero transition probabilities don’t sum to $1$. I’d start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at your expression for making no change to $i$: it is wrong by a factor of $2$. If you double the diagonal elements of your matrix, it should be OK. I'm guessing you calculated the probability of drawing a white ball followed by a red one, and neglected to consider the probability of doing it the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

The three expressions that you have for the nonzero transition probabilities don’t add up to $1$, so the problem lies there. They’re all governed by a hypergeometric distribution, so you should have $$\Pr(X_{k+1}=i-1 \mid X_k=i) = {\binom i 2 \binom{n-i+1} 0 \over \binom {n+1}2} \\ \Pr(X_{k+1}=i \mid X_k=i) = {\binom i 1 \binom{n-i+1} 1 \over \binom {n+1}2} \\ \Pr(X_{k+1}=i+1 \mid X_k=i) = {\binom i 0 \binom{n-i+1} 2 \over \binom {n+1}2}.$$ If you simplify these expressions, you’ll find that the probability for no change in the number of white balls is off by a factor of two.